# How to modify a dict item in a list

Tags: python

I have a list made of dictionaries

```
bookLogger = [
{'BookName': 'Noise', 'Author': 'Daniel Kahneman', 'Process': 'Reading' },
{'BookName': 'Superintelligence', 'Author': 'Nick Bostrom', 'Process': 'Not Reading'}
]
```

Want a user to be able to input what they want to change the name to, so that `'BookName': 'Noise'` turns to `'BookName': 'Testing'`
What I've come up with

```
testing = input("Enter Book Name ")

def changeName(bookLogger, testing, Name):
    for options in bookLogger:
        if options['BookName'] == testing:
            options['BookName'] = Name

 changeName(bookLogger, "BookName", "Chicken")
```

EDIT: Got it to work by doing

```
Updated = input("Enter Book Name ")

def changeName(Name):
    for options in bookLogger:
        if options['BookName'] == Updated:
            options['BookName'] = Name
            print(bookLogger)
```

Comment: You have messed up the arguments. I suggests using meaningful names so you can see that for yourself

Comment: @buran Not in this case. The problem is that OP has messed the arguments. Lists and dicts are mutable so they can be modified inside functions (wether this is a good practice is another question)

Comment: @buran It does not matter.

Comment: Don't know why people are upvoting that it must be returned; it simply isn't true. You can modify a dict within a function without returning it. Just don't bind the object to a new symbol.

Comment: @theherk OP is not binding to a new name. The only reason this does not work is because they use the wrong arguments in the wrong places

Comment: @Shayan Because clearly it shows a lack of effort. This can easily be self-debugged

Comment: I think `options['BookName'] == testing` is never going to be a True statement.

Comment: @DeepSpace, I am new to coding python

Comment: @DeepSpace yes I know it could be. But you can take it easy probably.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. If you intend to modify the dict without returning a new dict, you can modify like this:

```py
def rename(books: list[dict], old: str, new: str) -> None:
    for book in books:
        if book["name"] == old:
            book["name"] = new


if __name__ == "__main__":
    books = [{"name": "BookName"}, {"name": "A Book"}]
    print(books)
    rename(books, "BookName", "Chicken")
    print(books)
```

Which yields:

```
[{'name': 'BookName'}, {'name': 'A Book'}]
[{'name': 'Chicken'}, {'name': 'A Book'}]
```

---

*note*: [Type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) are used here but not required. I was simply specifying, for clarity in this case, that the inputs needed to be a list of dicts and two strings. In addition, these features can be [enabled in some older versions of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#id6) using `future`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

Comment: Can you please explain this `books: list[dict]` piece?

Comment: Sure thing. I'll update.

Comment: I'll appreciate it.